# How to determine age with AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to figure out how to determine somebody's age in the form of years/months/days. For example, if I was born on `8/1/2014` and today is `9/15/2015` I would be  1 year, 1 month and 15 days old.

I know you can use `DateDiff()` to determine the difference in Days; but, I'm not sure how to convert that number into years/months/days. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using both of your guys direction combined with the help of one of my colleagues I was finally able to figure this out. The code I ended up using is below in case anyone needs it later down the road. Thanks again for everyone's support on this one.

```
%%[
SET @dob = '2014-08-01'
SET @today = '2015-09-15'

SET @years = DateDiff(@dob, @today, "Y")
SET @months = DateDiff(DateAdd(@dob, @years, "Y") , @today, "M")
SET @days = DateDiff(DateAdd(DateAdd(@dob, @months, "M"), @years, "Y"), @today, "D")
OUTPUT(Concat(@years, IIF(@years > 0, IIF(@years > 1, "-years ", "-year "), ""), @months, IIF(@months > 0, IIF(@months > 1, "-months ", "-month "), ""), @days, IIF(@days > 0, IIF(@days > 1, "-days", "-day"), "")))
]%%
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to write an block of AMPScript to accomplish this.  It is not the most elegant, but it works.  The key is to use the AMPScript functions **DatePart**, **DateParse**, **DateAdd**, & **DateDiff** to calculate some key dates between now and the original date of birth  (or any past date for that matter).

```
%%[ 
var @days, @years, @months
var @dob, @lastBDay
var @dt1 /* now */
var @dt2 /* lastBDay + months */
var @dt2 /* now - (lastDay + months)  */

set @dt1 = Now()
set @dob = "7/4/1976"
set @lastBDay = DateParse(concat(Datepart(@dt1,"year"),"-",Datepart(@dob,"month"),"-",Datepart(@dob,"day")))
if (datediff(@lastBDay,@dt1,"D") < 0) then
    set @lastBDay = DateParse(concat(Datepart(DateAdd(@dt1,-1,"Y"),"year"),"-",Datepart(@dob,"month"),"-",Datepart(@dob,"day")))
endif

set @years = DateDiff(@dob,@dt1,"Y")
set @months = DateDiff(@lastBDay,@dt1,"M")
set @dt2 = DateAdd(@lastBDay,@months,"M")
set @days = DateDiff(@dt2,@dt1, "D")

]%%
<pre>
input date = %%=v(@dob)=%%

years = %%=v(@years)=%%
months = %%=v(@months)=%%
days = %%=v(@days)=%%
</pre>
```

**output:**

```
input date = 7/4/1976

years = 39
months = 1
days = 23
```

p.s.
Here's an online site you can use to validate against.
http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=7&d1=4&y1=1976&m2=8&d2=27&y2=2015

Comment: is it just me or the years, months and days are strings? I tried to do some math with the results and I cannot make it work. Do you guys have any luck? Everything else works so far, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I *THINK* it can be done with simple calculations - I have not tried it out yet for sure.

You may be slightly off since you would have to do average number of months in a year (unless you went super crazy with calculations and IF statements), but this should get you in the general direction. You can also use Hour and Minutes if you want to get super crazy.

```
%%[

VAR @Bday, @Month, @Day, @Year, @subtract, @total

SET @Bday = "" /* Info pulled from DE */
SET @Month = DateDiff(@Bday,NOW(), "M")
SET @Day = DateDiff(@Bday,NOW(), "D")
SET @Year = DateDiff(@Bday,NOW(), "Y")

IF @Year > 0 THEN
    SET @subtract = Multiply(@Year, 12)
    SET @total = Subtract(@Month, @subtract)
    SET @Month = @total
    SET @subtract = MULTIPLY(@Year, 365)
    SET @total = Subtract(@Day, @subtract)
    SET @Day = @total
ENDIF

IF @Month > 0 THEN
    SET @subtract = Multiply(@Month, 30)
    SET @total = Subtract(@Day, @subtract)
    SET @Day = @total
ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: What would the output be?

Comment: Could output through variable (%%=v(@Day)=%%) or through Output function (%%=Output(@Day)=%%) and for complex versioning can use if and concat or iif function to display only relevant data. Eg if there is no year value, do not display year language or value.