# Calculate the years of contract using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, formula, contracts

I have a field (Account: Created Date) in dd/MM/YYYY format. I want to have a formula that calculates the number of years that the account has been working with us to date. Can you please advise?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89637/how-to-determine-age-with-ampscript  Your query is answered here check it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Datediff](https://ampscript.guide/datediff/) function in Ampscript

Sample Code:

```
%%[
SET @today = Now()
SET @accountDate = CreatedDate //this should be your field, assuming it's in the sendable DE
SET @diffYear = dateDiff(@today , @accountDate,"Y")
]%%
%%=v(@diffYear)=%%
```

Comment: Thank you, Swati! I've tried your formula and it worked for one account when I set a specific value for the @accountDate. But how can I make it work for other accounts?

Comment: I've tried set @accountDate = %%Account: Created Date%% (as in the sendable DE)

Comment: You should use set @accountDate = [Created Date]

Comment: wow, it works perfectly well. You are genius! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well the Ampscript guide is written by Adam, he should be the one praised :). You can mark the answer as accepted, so that it's useful for someone else :)

Comment: Sorry, I have another issue relating to this. My field's value is set as dd/MM/YYY, therefore, it shows the error "Invalid value for function parameter" when the date is for example 25/11/2016. Is there any way I can override this date format?

Comment: Trying formating the date using FormatDate function and then calculating the difference

Comment: Thanks so much @Swati!